# Xcode installing on mac

Tags: xcode

I am new to mac and I want to install Xcode. I have macOS Sierra Version 10.12.2. I found online that I have to run in terminal:

```
xcode-select --install
```

I did that but I get this:

```
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates
```

However, I can't find it in Application folder or with Spotlight Search and there is no Software Update to be done. Also, I found online that I have to download it from App Store and I am a bit confused. I can install it from terminal (and if so, why is it not working) or I have to download it from App Store?

Thank you!

Comment: You can get it from the App Store. That will download a .dmg file to your Download folder. Then you double click on it to install. No idea what you're trying to do on the command line.  And that error implies that you already have Xcode (previous version?) on that device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't install Xcode from terminal, you have to go to develloper.apple.com in order to download the latest versions. Here's the link to save you some time:

[Link to Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/)

Plus the version available depends on what Mac Osx version you have.

Comment: So the one form App Store is not the right one? Or is it the same as the one from the link?

Comment: They both work, I just think It's better when you download it on the website, so then you can download many different versions.

Comment: You can install xCode from the terminal, its just sometimes this error happens and you have to go to apple developers.

Answer (score 2):

> xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use
>   "Software Update" to install updates

It shows that your operating system has already installed xcode-select.

Finding your xcode-select. Go to Terminal and type

```
xcode-select --print-path
```

It shall return the location of your xcode-select to you:

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

**Xcode**: develop an app for Apple products 
**xcode-select**: command-line tool

Depending on what you want to do with Xcode, xcode-select is way smaller than it, 8.1GB vs. nothing.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. The OP was asking how to install Xcode, not how to find where it is, nor how to find the location of the utility used

Comment: @TheeSritabtim Thanks for pointing it out. The question has ambiguity whether the OP wants Xcode or xcode-select. From the codes, it seems the OP wanted to install xcode-select. From the question title, the OP wants Xcode. Since others have shown the way: Install from the app store. So I want to show a way to xcode-select.

Answer (score 1):

2018 and I had the same issue. Installing XCODE from the App Store did not resolve this.

I Had to download the command line tools for my XCODE and Apple Version.

https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Searched for XCODE on that page above and picked the right version for me.

After installation of the DMG I could continue with Brew Installation.

Comment: It's also worth notice that it's the same problem for command lines extensions, they need to be downloaded too from developper.apple.com

Answer (score 0):

Was having the same issue after some system update, cannot even run things like `make install`.

1. verify your path by `xcode-select --print-path`, which might be `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`(need to be updated at last)
2. go to [apple develper site](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/), login, search `command line tools`, download the latest `dmg`, install. (better option than the 10+GB `Xcode`)
3. now update the path in step 1 by running `sudo xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`.
4. verify again by running the `xcode-select --print-path`.

Now it should be good to go.